# Hi. I need to move the cell red from the middle in all table, not only left-right, also up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i don't know how i can do the red cell from the middle to move also up and down, from the keyboard arrows. And she need to stop at the end of the row. Can anybody help me? This is the right code for what i need to do?

```html
<style type="text/css">
td {
  width: 50px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:blue;
}
.red{
  background: red;
}
}
</style>
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.middle').on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass('red');
  });
  $(document).keyup(function( event ) {
    var index;
    if($('.middle').hasClass("red")){
      if(event.which==39){
        index = $('.middle').index("td");
        index = ~~index;
        index+=1;
        if($("td").length == index){
          index = 0;
        }
        $('.middle').insertAfter($("td").eq(index));
        //$center.insertAfter(index);
      } else if(event.which==37){
        index = $('.middle').index("td");
        index = ~~index;
        index-=1;
        $('.middle').insertBefore($("td").eq(index));
      }
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>


<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td >-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td class="middle">-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
 </tr>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
 </tr>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And we are not going to do your homework

Comment: Have you tried somthing so far?

Comment: I posted what i tried.

Comment: I need just the middle cell to color. In my code every cell is color in red.

Comment: Great that you add your code! Now, you want that every click on you table (no matter the cell) change the color of your cell in the middle (x=3, y=3), rigth?

Comment: No. Just on click in that cell. When i click in the rest of the table, do not happen nothing, but when i click on the specified cell, she make red.

Comment: Check my answer, and let me know if it is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.middle').on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass('red');
  });
  $(document).keyup(function( event ) {
    var index;
    if($('.middle').hasClass("red")){
      if(event.which==39){
        index = $('.middle').index("td");
        index = ~~index;
        index+=1;
        if($("td").length == index){
          index = 0;
        }
        $('.middle').insertAfter($("td").eq(index));
        //$center.insertAfter(index);
      } else if(event.which==37){
        index = $('.middle').index("td");
        index = ~~index;
        index-=1;
        $('.middle').insertBefore($("td").eq(index));
      }
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  width: 50px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:blue;
}
.red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td >-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td class="middle">-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But i need that cell to move in every other cell of the table, not only left-right.

Comment: @DanDuca see again

Comment: It's the same thing. I need to move the cell also from ''up'' and ''down'' arrows.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the comment, what is requiered is to change the color of the **middle cell** (x=3, y=3), so we need to add an `id` to your **middle cell**:

```
...
<tr>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td id="middle-cell">-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
</tr>
...
```

And then change your function to select it:

```
<script>
$( function() {
  $("#middle-cell").click( function() {
    $("#middle-cell").css('background', 'red')
  } );
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Sure, at least I can try. But first [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and then post another question, so everyone can try to help you.